# Regex replace problems with \\

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I created my own regex, and everything work fine except the backslash thing. I tried my versions, but none of them helped.

```
var regexItem = new Regex("[^A-Za-z0-9_.,&/*:;=+{}()'\"\\ -]+");
string temp2 = "";
while ((@line = file2.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    if (regexItem.IsMatch(line) && (line.Contains(".jpg") || line.Contains(".png") || line.Contains(".jpeg") || line.Contains(".svg")))
    {
        @temp2 = Regex.Replace(line, "[^A-Za-z0-9_.,&/\\*:;=+{}()'\" -]+", "");
        postki.WriteLine(@temp2);
        Console.WriteLine(@"{0} ==> {1}", @line, @temp2);
    }
    else
    {
        postki.WriteLine(@line);
    }
}
```

Comment: Backslash is a special character in _both_ regex and C#. If you want to use a literal backslash in your pattern, then you need to escape it both in regex and in C#.

Comment: Actually, I don't understand it. :'D

Comment: Sometimes it's easier to pull out characters that need to be escaped: `char doubleQuote = '"'; string s = "he said," + doubleQuote + "hello!" + doubleQuote;`

Answer (score 1):

In c# string *literals*, special characters (like `"`) need to be escaped. C# uses the `\` to escape those characters.

For example - as you already did - a string containing a `"` would be declared like that:

```
string quote = "\"";
```

So of course the backslash itself needs escapting, too. So a string containing a back-slash would look like this:

```
string backslash = "\\";
```

So with two backslashs in the *literal*, you have one real backslash in the string.

But a backslash also is a special character in regular expressions (also used to escape other symbols, for example if you mean a literal `.` instead of the *any-character-dot*, you use `\.`). So to use a literal backslash (meaning to match a single backslash in the search string) you need to use 4 back-slashes in your c# string literal:

```
string regexBackSlash = "\\\\";
```

In your regex you probably meant:

```
var regexItem = new Regex("[^A-Za-z0-9_.,&/*:;=+{}()'\"\\\\ -]+");
                                     // difference here ^
```

Or you may use verbatim string literals (with a leading `@`):

```
var regexItem = new Regex(@"[^A-Za-z0-9_.,&/*:;=+{}()'""\\ -]+");
```

(but then again you need to escape the `"` with a second one).